# Como criar servidor IPTV

Tags: servidor

Olá, pessoal não sei se é o lugar certo pra fazer essa pergunta, mas vi que o fórum ajuda bastante os usuários, o que eu queria saber era o seguinte.

Como criar um servidor IPTV, já procurei em tudo que é lugar e ninguém fala como que cria, ouvi falar por terceiros que é muito caro, outros falaram que precisa de placa de captura, vps, tv por assinatura e etc, me ajudem ou me indique alguém que possa me ajudar, obrigado.

OBS: se essa pergunte foge dos termos do fórum, algum moderador possa excluir, por favor, para que eu não seja punido.

Comment: Não há punição por postar algo que não se encaixe no nosso site de Q&A. O que pode ocorrer é ser bloqueado automaticamente pelo sistema se postar muita coisa ruim e não consertar. Ela parece ampla e talvez fora de escopo.

Comment: Para que você não tenha mais medo, dê uma lida em [quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic)

Comment: Um projeto opensource que pode lhe ajudar: https://github.com/tvheadend/tvheadend